# yodeya.com/* links are not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, site-name

When I browse to http://yodeya.com/q/1 or http://mi.yodeya.com/q/1, I get a blank page. These URLs ought to (and used to) resolve to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1, and in general, `yodeya.com/*` and `mi.yodeya.com/*` should resolve to `judaism.stackexchange.com/*`.

We have used these links in our four publications with, collectively, thousands of print copies in circulation.  The last thing we want is for a recipient of a book to actually check out a URL found therein, only to get a blank page and conclude "eh, guess those guys don't exist any more".

Comment: This is happening to me too, including in an incognito window (just in case some extension were in play, not that I could think of a relevant one).

Comment: This is still happening (so, not a transient error).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Do you know if SO staff are aware of it?

Comment: I've nudged them, yes.  They probably didn't notice before today because of the secular holidays.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks. I'd call Winter Bash rather parochial in nature, more than secular! And if you consider the SE gospel of online Q&A communities to be a religion ...

Comment: I'm talking with our SRE team to track down the problem. Do you have a sense of when they stopped working? It's been a few years since we made any changes on our configuration. It's possible the issue is with the domain's registrar.

Comment: @JonEricson I don't recall noticing the issue until shortly (days?) before I posted it, but I don't know for sure. I can set a lower bound of May 27, 2016, since I see that I (via @mi_yodeya) [tweeted out](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya/status/736187611287539712) a mi.yodeya.com link on that day.

Comment: If it helps, the error is still there for me (although navigating to "yodeya.com" still works).

Comment: @JonEricson in case it helps influence prioritization: we use these links in our publications, two of which will be "in season" and thus distributed more soon: Purim in mid-March and Pesach in mid-April.  Having these links working soon would be really helpful; the last thing we want is for a recipient of a book to actually check out a URL found therein, only to get a blank page and conclude "eh, guess those guys don't exist any more".  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Isaac, I think the publication concern is sufficiently noteworthy to be included explicitly in the question.

Comment: @JonEricson Maybe I misunderstood the situation in your answer, but shouldn't this be [meta-tag:status-deferred] or [meta-tag:status-planned] instead of [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've updated some things in cloudflare: I expect the following links to all work (after dns propagation):

- http://yodeya.com/questions/12760
- https://yodeya.com/questions/12760
- https://www.yodeya.com/questions/12760
- http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/12760
- https://mi.yodeya.com/questions/12760
- http://meta.yodeya.com/questions/4171
- http://meta.mi.yodeya.com/questions/4171
- https://meta.yodeya.com/questions/4171
- https://meta.mi.yodeya.com/questions/4171
- https://chat.yodeya.com
- http://chat.mi.yodeya.com

And miyodeya as well:

- http://miyodeya.com/questions/12760
- https://miyodeya.com/questions/12760
- http://meta.miyodeya.com/questions/4171
- https://meta.miyodeya.com/questions/4171
- http://chat.miyodeya.com

If any of those don't, or if there are others that should, please let me know.

I'm working on generalizing the solution, so that we can easily apply it to all of the similar network site aliases.

Looks like things like https://meta.mi.yodeya.com do not work with cloudflare free because they only get a cert for `*.yodeya.com`, so multi level subdomains are http only.

Comment: Thank you for your work on this!

Answer (score 7):

After some discussion with our SRE team, I have some good news: these redirects will be working by the end of Shabbat.<sup>*</sup> There are a couple of caveats, however:

1. We are using [Cloudflare's free plan](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/) which doesn't really offer a service level agreement (SLA).
2. HTTPS is included so you can use links like: https://yodeya.com/q/1 It's possible that service will go away. If that happens, we may not be able to make them work again. Unless you really need HTTPS, I would avoid it.

I don't think either of these will be problems for you all. If Cloudflare changes their service in a way that breaks these links again, it should be a lot easier to get things worked out in the future.

On that note: I need to apologize to you all for the amount of time it took to get this all worked out. I misunderstood some information early on that led me to pursue entirely the wrong path. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you for being so patient and graceful with me.

---

<sup>* It's not that the servers are observant, but rather it can take up to 24 hours for the change to propagate. Depending on where you are,
 they might be working already.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for getting back to us. I don't understand why question-level redirection works on other sites with custom domains and not here. That is, http://nothingtoinstall.com/q/1 redirects to a question, as does http://seasonedadvice.com/q/1. However, http://yodeya.com/q/1 redirects to a blank page. Why is this site different from all other sites?

Comment: Huh. I could have sworn that as I was writing that comment, http://nothingtoinstall.com/q/1 worked. Now, it doesn't, same as http://yodeya.com/q/1. Maybe I was mistaken. However http://seasonedadvice.com/q/1 does indeed work. I can't verify http://thearqade.com/q/1/ right this minute, because my work blocks that domain. Is Seasoned Advice set up differently from other custom-named sites?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I just checked http://thearqade.com/q/1 and it doesn't work. Jon's got a lead on how to continue investigating, though, so hopefully we'll know more in a few days (a blind estimate I just made up so don't hold him to it!).

Comment: Jon, thanks for investigating.  @hairboat does your comment mean that status-declined is premature, or do y'all mean that we should assume we're not getting this but maybe we'll get lucky?

Comment: @IsaacMoses if we had control of the domain again would we be able to make it work?  (That is, is the problem specific to SE's hosting?)  If so and if hairboat's idea doesn't go anywhere, Jon, what would it take to regain control of the domain?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I'm not sure yet. (How's that for noncommittal? ;-) This seems to have fallen through the cracks between SRE and the Q&A development teams. I've got a meeting tomorrow that might result in a solution. If not, I'm going to suggest returning the domain to y'all. It's not very useful in the current state.

Comment: @Monica It took me about five minutes to set up http://yodeya.club/q/1 via namecheap.com, so I expect it wouldn't be too hard to do the same for yodeya.com.

Comment: @JonEricson thank you for the great news in this update!  We really appreciate the work that the team put in to track this down.

Comment: The yodeya.com URL in the question is working for me (yay!), but the mi.yodeya.com one is failing with a DNS error.  Could propagation for the one still be delayed (while the other works)?

Comment: Same as @Monica

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I think this was an oversight. I'm checking to see if we can add mi.yodeya.com as a redirect. Do you know if there are any other subdomains that people might use? I can't imagine any, but just in case. . .

Comment: @JonEricson thanks!  I don't know of any others, but I just asked in our chat room in case there's something I don't know about.

Comment: chat link http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37280748#37280748

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a userscript to fix the issue for now.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Redirect broken Mi Yodeya links
// @version      0.1
// @author       Scimonster
// @include     http://*.*
// @include     https://*.*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    var targ = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if ( targ && targ.href && targ.href.match(/https?:\/\/.*\.yodeya.com/) ) {
        targ.href = targ.href.replace(/https?:\/\/.*\.yodeya.com/, 'http://judaism.stackexchange.com');
    }
});
})();
```

(Based on [this userscript](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/487275).)

Comment: Thanks, but my primary concern is for the many existing links already in the wild (including printed in our publications) that use the yodeya.com domain.